# F# instead of multiple lets , can I pipe the intermediate results

Tags: json, dictionary, f#

Given:

```
let json = """
{
    "KeyValuePairs": "[{\"Key\" : \"one\", \"Value\" : \"1\"},{\"Key\" : \"two\", \"Value\" : \"2\"}]"
}
"""
let dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<System.String, System.String>>(json) 
let kvpairs = dict.["KeyValuePairs"]
let kvlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<System.String, System.String> List>(kvpairs)
let kvmap = [for kv  in kvlist -> (kv.Key, kv.Value)] |> Map.ofList
```

Can I use one expression with pipes instead of intermediate variables?  If so, what would that look like?

FWIW I tried:

```
let kvpairs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<System.String, System.String>>(json) 
    |> (fun d -> d.["KeyValuePairs"])
```

but that gave me the error:

> ```
> error FS0010: Unexpected infix operator in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other
> ```
>
> token.

Update:  What about the other way around: piping into JsonConvert?

```
let kvpairs = 
    json
    |> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<System.String, System.String>>
    |> (fun d -> d.["KeyValuePairs"])
```

This gives me:

> error FS0717: Unexpected type arguments

Comment: What wrong with giving names to intermediate values? Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: I'm learning F# and want to learn about different ways of doing things. Not that there's anything wrong with intermediate names

Comment: The code in your last update works for me without compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
let kvpairs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<System.String, System.String>>(json) 
    |> (fun d -> d.["KeyValuePairs"])
```

The pipe is not indented far enough.

```
let kvpairs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<System.String, System.String>>(json) 
              |> (fun d -> d.["KeyValuePairs"])
```

or

```
let kvpairs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<System.String, System.String>>(json) 
           |> (fun d -> d.["KeyValuePairs"])
```

or

```
let kvpairs = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<System.String, System.String>>(json) 
    |> (fun d -> d.["KeyValuePairs"])
```

will work.

Comment: Thanks, the indentation worked.  Now, I updated the example with an attempt to pipe into JsonConvert.  Can this work somehow?

Comment: Now you have a typo (and forgot the "(json)" argument on the end of the JC.DO function call)

Comment: yes, that's what I meant to do.  I'm trying to pipe the variable "json" into the call to JsonConvert.  Did I get that wrong?